# Объединение PHP запроса и скрипта autocomplete в одном файле

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, autocomplete

Подскажите пожалуйста как изменить название источника `source:` при объединении в одном файле `pg_query` с получением и реформированием массива и скрипта `autocomplete`, которые сегодня работают в двух файлах:
`street.php`

```js
<?php
require_once ("pg_conn.php");

$qstreet = "SELECT
   cmac.street.id, 
   cmac.street.street,
   cmac.street.postcode,
   cmac.street.id_dimos,
   cmac.street.id_street
   FROM
   cmac.street";  

$ress = pg_query ($qstreet);
  while ( $row = pg_fetch_array ( $ress ) ) {
  $array[]=$row[1];    
  }
 
   if (!empty($_GET['term']))       
    {
        $term = $_GET['term'];
  $pattern = '/^'.preg_quote($term).'/iu';
  echo json_encode(preg_grep($pattern, $array));
    }
?>
```

`area.html`

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/style.css" />
  <title></title>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.3/themes/sunny/jquery-ui.css">

  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('#street').autocomplete({
        source: 'street.php'
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <form method="post">

        <tr>
          <td><label for="street">Street:</label></td>
          <td><input type="text" placeholder="Street name" required="required" id="street" name="street" onchange="sendForm(this.form)"></td>
        </tr>
        -----------------------
      </form>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

чтобы в новом, объединённом файле `area.php`, в РНР части проходила выборка и создание массива, а скрипт вставлял его в выпадающий список, как-то типа этого, вместо ссылки на внешний файл:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#street').autocomplete({
    source: ($pattern, $array)
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задача решена @romach с php.ru, может кому-то пригодится

```js
$(function() {
  $('#street').autocomplete({
    source: <?= json_encode($array) ?>
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Вместо

```
echo json_encode(preg_grep($pattern, $array));
```

сохраняете в массив

```
$autocomplete = preg_grep($pattern, $array);
```

А в select выводите через foreach. Так чтоли?

Comment: @p-c...ход мысли понятен, но как передать новую переменную $autocomplete из РНР части в HTML?

Comment: Если эти два файла будут объеденены, то она там уже будет. Если html как шаблон, то подключить его после выполнения скрипта.

Comment: с утра проверил, не работает, 
`    $ac = preg_grep($pattern, $array);`
сделал в скрипте переменную ` var st = '<?php echo $ac ?>';
$(function() {   
 $('#street').autocomplete({
   source: st  
  });
 } 
); `
в консоли пишет ` Undefined variable: ac`

Comment: Покажите как подключаете шаблон?